# c# sslstream sending data in chunks

Tags: c#, http, webserver, sslstream, transfer-encoding

I am trying to send data via sslstream from my c# webserver to a Browser.
For some reason "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" is not working. 
Do you see any mistakes in my code below:

```
string header = HTTPServer.VERSION + " " + status + "\r\nContent-Type: " + mine + "\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n";
sslstream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header));

int total = data.Length;
int sent = 0;
int buffer = 2048;
string hex;

while (total > 0)
{
    if (total < buffer)
        buffer = total;
    hex = buffer.ToString("X");
    sslstream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hex + "\r\n"));
    sslstream.Write(data, sent, buffer);
    sslstream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n"));
    sent += buffer;
    total -= buffer;
}
buffer = 0;
hex = buffer.ToString("X");
sslstream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hex + "\r\n"));
sslstream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n"));
sslstream.Flush();
sslstream.Close();
```

Thank you!

Comment: define "is not working"; what happens, and how does this differ from what you expected to happen?

Comment: Browsers error message is "ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING", when im not using "transfer-encoding:chunked" data transfer works fine. In order to transfer large amount of data I want to implement chunked transfer. Thank you!

Comment: does it work without the TLS? to be honest, you're probably going to need to look at the raw generated byte stream (perhaps via fiddler or similar) to figure this out

Comment: ok thank you, I will have a look.